# Keeping an Image and text in proportion with Bootstrap until image folds on top of text,

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an image next to text that is vertically aligned to the image on large screens. See code below and attached image.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<?php add_revslider('homepage'); ?>

<div id="front-page-1" class="row h-100">
<div class="col-lg-6">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500x1500?text=1500px+by+1500px" class="img-fluid" alt="temp" />
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 my-auto">
<span>WHAT WE DO</span>
<h2>Defending Information Rights</h2>

<p>The BC Freedom of Information and Privacy Association (FIPA) is a non-partisan,
non-profit society that was established in 1991 to promote and defend freedom
of information and privacy rights in Canada. Our goal is to empower citizens by
increasing their access to information and their control over their own personal
information. We serve a wide variety of individuals and organizations through
programs of public education, public assistance, research, and law reform. We
are one of very few public interest groups in Canada devoted solely to the
advancement of freedom of information (FOI) and privacy rights.</p>

<p>We were the major force in getting BC’s Freedom of Information and Protection
of Privacy Act passed, and we are its main defender. This act has been called the
most progressive legislation of its kind in the world.</p>
<ul>
<li>We seek to empower citizens by increasing their right of access to
government-held information</li>
<li>We seek to empower citizens by promoting and defending the principle of
universal and affordable access to the basic information channels of our time</li>
<li>We seek to empower citizens by limiting the surveillance activities of the state,
and by increasing our right of access to our own personal information and our
ability to control the collection, use and sharing of our personal information,
wherever it is stored</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div> <!--end container-fluid-->
```

I would like the heights of the two columns to remain the same until the image folds on top of the text at 992px (boostrap breakpoint for large). I would like to preserve the look of the text next to the image until the break occurs (see image). What is the best way to do this with boostrap 4 ? The text size would have to be reduced to fit next to the image as the screen gets smaller ?

[image: Image and Text]

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `h-100` class to each `col` elements will force them to respect the `row` element height:

```
<main><div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 h-100 border border-danger">
    <!-- left content-->
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 h-100 border border-danger">
    <!-- right content-->
  </div>
</div></main>
```